# (Proof verification) Extension Lemma for Functions on Submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, smooth-manifolds

[There is a similar question about this lemma in Lee's book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299694/extension-lemma-for-functions-on-submanifolds), but I wasn't really satisfied with the detail in the proposed solution. In particular, the OP of the linked question doesn't describe how to get the smooth maps which I am calling $f_p$ below. I am hoping someone can give critical feedback on this proof and point out where, if anywhere, I have erred.

> **Lemma 5.34 (Extension Lemma for Functions on Submanifolds).** Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold, $S\subset M$ is a smooth submanifold,
>   and $f\in C^\infty(S)$.
>
> 1. If $S$ is embedded, then there exist a neighborhood $U$ of $S$ in $M$
>      and a smooth function $\widetilde f\in C^\infty(U)$ such that $\widetilde f|_S = f$.
> 2. If $S$ is properly embedded, then the neighborhood $U$ in part (a) can be taken to be all of $M$.

***Proof of 1:***

Let $n = \dim S$ and $m = \dim M$. Since $S$ is embedded, each $p\in S$ is in the domain of
a slice chart $(U_p,\varphi_p)$ in $M$ such that $S\cap U_p$ is a single slice
in $U$. Since $f$
is smooth, at each $p\in S$ we can find a slice chart so that $\mathbf{f}_p:= f\circ\varphi_p^{-1}\colon \varphi_p(S\cap
U_p)\to\Bbb R$ is smooth. Since $\varphi_p(S\cap U_p) = \{(x^1,\dots,x^n,0,\dots,0)\in
\varphi_p(U_p)\}$, and $\mathbf{f}_p$ is smooth on this set, there is a smooth extension
$\widehat f_p\colon V_p\subset\Bbb R^m\to \Bbb R$ of $\mathbf{f}_p$, where $V_p$ is an open set in $\Bbb R^m$ containing $\varphi(p)$.

(Here is where I see a potential "bug" in this proof. By the definition of a smooth map on $S$, the map $\mathbf{f}_p$ is "smooth." However, since $\mathbf{f}_p$ is defined on a set that is not an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$, I believe, and please do address this point, "smooth" means that there is the extension I am calling $\widehat f_p$.)

The restriction of $\widehat f_p$ to the open set
$W_p := \varphi_p(U_p)\cap V_p $ is still smooth and gives us a map
$f_p\colon \varphi_p^{-1}(W_p)\to\Bbb R$ defined by $f_p(x) = \big(\widehat f_p|_{W_p}\big)\circ\varphi_p(x)$.

The collection of open sets $\varphi_p^{-1}(W_p)$ is an open cover of $S$,
so let $(\psi_p)_{p\in S}$ be a partition of unity subordinate to this cover. For any $x\in U:=\bigcup_{p\in S}\varphi^{-1}(W_p)$, define $\widetilde f(x) = \sum_{p\in S}\psi_p(x)f_p(x)$. If $x\in S$, then
$$
\widetilde f(x) = \sum_{p\in S}\psi_p(x) f(x) = f(x).
$$
Hence $\widetilde f$ is an extension of $f$. Since the collection of supports of the  $\psi_p$ is locally finite, each point in
$U$ has a neighborhood in which the sum is finite, so this defines
a smooth map since every point has a neighborhood such that $\widetilde f$ restricted
to that neighborhood is smooth. Hence $\widetilde f\in C^\infty(U)$ is the desired
extension. $\square$

***Proof of 2:***

In this case, the only thing that changes is that $S$ is actually closed in $M$ by a lemma in Lee's book. By appending
$M\smallsetminus S$ to the collection $\{\varphi_p^{-1}(W_p)\}$ and taking a partition of unity
$\{\psi_p: p\in S\}\cup\{\psi_0\}$ subordinate to this open cover of $M$
with $\operatorname{supp}\psi_0\subset M\smallsetminus S$, 
define $\widetilde f(x) = \psi_0(x) + \sum_{p\in S}\psi_p(x)f_p(x)$, where $f_p$ is
defined in the first part. $\square$

Answer (score 5):

I heartily welcome feedback, but I believe the proof in my question works. The first section where I thought the proof was lacking can indeed be improved. I got the idea for the improvement from the hint to Exercise 2.3 in Lee's *Riemannian Manifolds*, restated here for interest:

> **Exercise 2.3.** Suppose $M\subset \widetilde M$ is an embedded submanifold.

> (a) If $f$ is any smooth function on $M$, show that $f$ can be extended to a smooth function on $\widetilde M$ whose restriction to $M$ is $f$. [Hint: Extend $f$ locally in slice coordinates by letting it be independent of $(x^{n+1},\dots,x^m)$, and patch that together using a partition of unity.]

Here is the improved proof of 1:

Let $n = \dim S$. Since $S$ is embedded, each $p\in S$ is in the domain of
a slice chart $(U_p,\varphi_p)$ in $M$ such that $f|_{S\cap U_p} = f(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ and
the $x^i$ are slice coordinates. By further restricting the set $U_p$ if necessary (say to be a centered coordinate cube on $\varphi_p(p)$), we also ensure that $(x_1,\dots,x_m)\in\varphi_p(U_p)$ implies $(x_1,\dots,x_n,0,\dots,0)\in \varphi_p(S\cap U_p)$. Extend $f|_{S\cap U_p}$ to $U_p$ by setting
$f_p(x^1,\dots,x^n,x^{n+1},\dots,x^m) = f|_{S\cap U_p}(x^1,\dots,x^n)$. The restriction that $(x_1,\dots,x_m)\in \varphi_p(U_p)$ implies $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\varphi_p(S\cap U_p)$ ensures that the extension is well defined thoughout $U_p$ (thanks to the comment by user @KarthikKannan for pointing this out). The map
$f_p\colon U_p\to\Bbb R$ is smooth because it is independent of its last $m-n$ coordinates
and it is smooth with respect to its first $n$ coordinates.

The collection of open sets $U_p$ is an open cover of $S$, so let $(\psi_p)_{p\in S}$ be
a partition of unity subordinate to this cover, and define $\widetilde f(x) = \sum_{p\in S}
\psi_p(x)f_p(x)$. If $x\in S$, then
$$
\widetilde f(x) = \sum_{p\in S}\psi_p(x) f(x) = f(x).
$$
Hence $\widetilde f$ is an extension of $f$.

Since the collection of supports of the  $\psi_p$ is locally finite, each point in
$U$ has a neighborhood in which the sum is finite, so this defines
a smooth map since every point has a neighborhood such that $\widetilde f$ restricted
to that neighborhood is smooth. Hence $\widetilde f\in C^\infty(U)$ is the desired
extension. $\square$

The proof of 2 is modified by replacing $\varphi_p^{-1}(W_p)$ with $U_p$ defined in the modified proof of 1 above. $\square$

---

The reason that the original proof still works is that the extensions I describe in the first proof of 1 can be taken to be the $f_p$ explicitly described in the proof in this answer. The approach taken here simplifies some of the notation and construction of the extension $f_p$ by blurring the distinction between points $p$ in the manifold and their local coordinate representations $(x^1,x^2,x^3,\dots)$. Smoothness of the coordinate representation of $f$ is equivalent to smoothness of the actual map defined on the manifold.

Comment: This is just a minor remark, but I think we must ensure that the image of $U_{p}$ under $\varphi_{p}$ must be cubical (possibly by restricting the original map to a smaller open set) in order to define the smooth extension $f_{p}$.

Comment: @KarthikKannan: That's an interesting thought. I am not sure I fully agree, however.  If the domain is not a cube, the definition of the function still shall give a smooth function by the definition of the slice coordinates, no?

Comment: I apologize if I'm incorrect. My reasoning is that if $\varphi_{p}(U_{p})$ is not a cube (or rectangle) then $(x_{1}, \dots, x_{m})\in \varphi_{p}(U_{p})$ does not necessarily imply that $(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}, 0, \dots, 0)$ (i.e. it's projection on the slice) is in $\varphi_{p}(S\cap U_{p})$.

Comment: @KarthikKannan: I think you are right! We must further restrict the open sets $U_p$, say by taking them to be cubical, or to be centered coordinate balls, so that the coordinate formula for $f_p$ throughout $U_p$ is allowed to use the slice coordinates.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Could you explain a bit more on why we must restrict the open sets as cubes or balls? I don't see why we don't get smooth functions without the restriction

Comment: I don't see why you need to restrict the set when by definition of slice charts the implication should follow.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician: Say in $\mathbb R^2$, $S$ is the real line, and I am looking at a slice chart for $S$ shaped like a "$\Gamma$" intersecting the real line, so it has a "hook" shape to it. My function $f(x_1)$ is defined on the segment intersecting the bottom portion of the $\Gamma$. If I try to define an extension $\tilde f(x_1,x_2) = f(x_1)$ throughout the whole $\Gamma$, my coordinate formula doesn't make sense once $(x_1,x_2)$ is in the upper-right portion of the $\Gamma$, since for those $(x_1,x_2)$, the $x_1$ coordinate is not in the domain of $f$ in my slice coordinates.